# How i can take the json's value in PHP?

Tags: php, json, xbox

I would like to know, how take the value "gamertag" from this Json (http://360api.chary.us/?gamertag=superdeder) with PHP.

i would print only the value "superdeder".

thanks a lot.

Andrea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and convert your JSON to an object with [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://360api.chary.us/?gamertag=superdeder');

$gamer = json_decode($json);
echo $gamer->Gamertag; // SuperDeder
```

Or, an array, by passing a truthy value as `json_decode()`s second parameter:

```
$gamer = json_decode($json, true);
echo $gamer['Gamertag']; // SuperDeder
```

Comment: it's perfect! And if i want print the value of AvailableAchievements?

Comment: You would need to loop through your `$gamer->LastPlayed` property.

Comment: Could you show how to do?

Comment: This is the solution:

$json = file_get_contents('http://360api.chary.us/?gamertag=superdeder');
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$users=$data['LastPlayed'];
foreach ($users as $user)
 {
    echo $user['AvailableAchievements'];
 }

Comment: One more question ..
I would like to print me "Tile32px."
How do I?
thanks

Comment: @AndreaAsrFranchi Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yesterday I was able to print the games but as I write I'm stuck on this other value.

Can not print it, I tried using the foreach!

Comment: Please [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) then. Remember to include what you have tried in the question.